# My animated gif stops working after 2 mins in all browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am dealing with ceiling fan animation and I use a `png` image when the fan is *off* and a `gif` image when it's *on*.

My image is switched successfully and the `gif` is displayed to indicate my fan is *on*. But after 2 mins my `gif` file stops working in all browsers.

How can I resolve that?

Here is my code:

```js
$(function() {
 var hit2 = 0;
 $('#tfanonoff').click(function() {
     if  (hit2 % 2 !== 0) {
            $("#foff").fadeIn().animate({'display':'inline-block'},1000);
      $("#fon").fadeOut(1000);
     } else { 
      $("#foff").fadeOut().animate({'display':'none'},1000);
      $("#fon").fadeIn().animate({'display':'inline-block'},1000);
        }
        hit2++;
        return false;
 });
});
```

```css
.ceiling-fan {
    max-width: 20%; 
    display: inline-block; 
    text-align: center; 
    left: 41%;  
    position: absolute; 
    transform: rotateX(-58deg);
}
```

```html
<img id="foff" class="img-responsive ceiling-fan" src="img/fanoff.png" alt="static-img" />
<img id="fon" class="img-responsive ceiling-fan" loop=infinite src="http://animationsa2z.com/attachments/Image/fans/ventilator4.gif" 
    style="display:none;" />
```

Comment: I believe the `loop=infinite` attribute is deprecated as of now, and it may cause the issue.

Comment: I removed loop=infinite but still same issue I have.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the gif has been set to a finite number of interations before the looping stops. You need to re-create the gif so that there are infinite number of iterations.

Comment: No bro its with infinite loop

Answer (score 0):

I have added the loop in your gif image please download from below URL

https://i.imgsafe.org/8b8138e463.gif

Comment: Thanks @santosh but how you add loop in gif  can u please tell me that?

Comment: And what if I increase my .gif speed ??

Comment: I added the loop using Photoshop software via timeline and You need to tweek your gif image in photoshop for increasing  speed